# pecl: command not found when trying to install PHP SQL Server driver

Tags: php, sql-server

I need to be able to access MSSQL databases from PHP and I'm trying to activate the driver to do so, since mssql php natively was removed after PHP 5.6.

Here's what I tried:

```
sudo su
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/7/prod.repo > /etc/yum.repos.d/mssql-release.repo
exit
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y yum install msodbcsql
sudo yum install unixODBC-devel
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
sudo pecl install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
sudo echo "extension= pdo_sqlsrv.so" >> `php --ini | grep "Loaded Configuration" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"`
sudo echo "extension= sqlsrv.so" >> `php --ini | grep "Loaded Configuration" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"`
```

I get the error message "pecl: command not found"

What can I do to get this installed?

Answer (score 1):

It seems `pecl` isn't installed.

On RHEL, you'd install it like this:

```
yum install php-pear
```

Comment: I tried that. I get the error "No package php-pear available."

Comment: @RickScolaro This is the correct command. If you got that message, you have set some inappropriate package exclusions on your yum repos, and you should remove these; or possibly your system is horribly broken and can't install anything, in which case you should seek further assistance with that.

Comment: I did check my exclusions and php* was there so I removed it. Now I get "
Transaction check error:
  file /usr/bin/php from install of php-cli-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ea-php-cli-1.0.0-9.9.4.cpanel.x86_64
"

Comment: Are you on a shared hosting? I'm gonna assume you are because of the "cpanel" part. You won't be able to install PECL there.